# React Native change Current Screen before Modal Close

Tags: react-native

[image]

when I'm on Screen 1 I open the Modal, when I close the Modal I want screen 2 to be behind the Modal. But I want the Screen to change before closing the Modal not after closing the Modal.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not share any code, I will just assume that you're using functional components.

I assume that your state is a local `useState`, let's say:

```
const [currentState, setState] = useState();
```

You can simply pass the `setState` to your `Modal` to change the current Screen's local state. So you just need to call the `setState` function and it should update the screen's local state.

## EDIT:

Ah, sorry. I just misunderstood your question.

You can use global modal for this.
You cannot change the current screen since you set the modal into that screen however, with the global modal. You can put the logic for this.

I can suggest you to use this since it is very intuitive and easy to use as global modal. You can any custom design inside of it.

https://github.com/WrathChaos/react-native-global-modal-2

If you do not want to use any library, you can simply check this library's code how it implements the global modal and you can set it for your own cases.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I know this way but I want to navigate to the other Screen.(with navigator)

Comment: Ah, sorry. I just misunderstood your question. 

You can use global modal for this. 
You cannot change the current screen since you set the modal into that screen however, with the global modal. You can put the logic for this. 

I can suggest you to use this since it is very intuitive and easy to use as global modal. You can any custom design inside of it. 

https://github.com/WrathChaos/react-native-global-modal-2


If you do not want to use any library, you can simply check this library's code how it implements the global modal and you can set it for your own cases.

Comment: I also, updated this post if someone else also needs this answer.